# SAP HANA convert YYYYWW to MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: sql, hana

The requirement is to get the Monday and Sunday from the field SPWOC in table S990. I cant think of any function combinations that would allow me to pull this information. An example output from that table-field is 202135. So I'm trying to get the Monday and Sunday from the 35th week of 2021. Any ideas on where to start would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are the Monday & Sunday for week 35 in 2021? Are week numbers based on ISO weeks?

Comment: I'm not 100%, but I think they're based on ISO weeks and that Sun is 8/29/2021 and Mon is 8/30/2021. If there is a definitive way to answer those questions I'd be happy to do it.

Comment: Then it's not ISO weeks, as they start on Monday

Comment: [ISO week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) starts on Monday, not on Sunday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether the ISO week calculation (that's the SAP standard default) is used or the system uses a non-ISO week calculation method cannot be determined from the table alone.

To find out about that, you need to talk to somebody that knows how the SAP system is configured.

But for the scope of the question, let's assume the system you work with uses the ISO method, where weeks start on Monday and end on Sunday.

Even with that, it's not straightforward to compute the dates for Monday and Sunday of the Xth week in a closed-form.
The `TO_DATE()` function does not support a direct conversion from `YYYYWW` to `YYYY-MM-DD` either.

So, apart from writing your own function to perform the right calendar arithmetic, I only see the following option as a feasible approach:

1. Ensure the HANA table `_SYS_BIC.M_TIME_DIMENSION` has been loaded with data (day-level) for the time frame you are interested in. This can be done via the **Generate Time Data** function in HANA Studio or the Web IDE. Check the documentation for details on that if required.
2. With the time dimension table you get all sorts of precomputed date representations and conversion, including `CALWEEK` and `DAY_OF_WEEK`.

With that you can run a SELECT like this:

```
select 
     year
   , week
   , date_sql
   , to_nvarchar( date_sql, 'DAY')
from 
    "_SYS_BI"."M_TIME_DIMENSION" 
where 
    calweek = '202135'
and day_of_week in (0, 6);


YEAR    WEEK    DATE_SQL    TO_NVARCHAR(DATE_SQL,'DAY')
2021    35      30/08/2021  MONDAY                     
2021    35      05/09/2021  SUNDAY
```